# I had created download page but it is not showing it is only showing in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blogger

it is showing only home page for download page also please anyone can help me out

my blog link - [my blog](https://ndsmndsm.blogspot.com/index.html)
my code(it is above 30000 character so I had shared docs link)

link of code -[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14jO8mWQSKTc2th3itYHA9H1P0ODuLwTjcol_OFI3fhc/edit?usp=sharing)

In download page section it is showing home page only when we click on download it doesn't show download page.